# Simpleform & Boostrap custom wrapper : inline radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

Using Simple Form & Bootstrap, is there a way to add a class on span class="radio" ? (with custom wrapper or wrapper_html ? ). I aim at putting all radio buttons inline (but not the main label 'Vous êtes').

Goal =

Vous êtes :

() Homme   () Femme

```
here is the code (haml) in my view :

= simple_form_for @user  do |f|
 = f.input :gender, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [["Homme", 0], ["Femme", 1]]

here is the html generated code :

<div class="form-group radio_buttons required user_gender">
 <label class="control-label radio_buttons required">
   Vous êtes :
 </label>
 <input type="hidden" name="user[gender]" value="">
 <span class="radio">
   <label for="user_gender_0">
     <input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" name="user[gender]" id="user_gender_0">
     Homme
   </label>
 </span>
 <span class="radio">
   <label for="user_gender_1">
     <input class="radio_buttons required" type="radio" value="1" name="user[gender]" id="user_gender_1">
     Femme
 </label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly, can't you just use 'display block' in your CSS? or simply wrap your main label within it's own containment div.

```
.control-label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank you harntrox, but this doesn't work for what I intend to do.

Comment: What do you intend to do? Can't think how you would manage this without containing either the main label or radio group. 

like so: https://jsfiddle.net/tbnyLwdu/

Comment: I would like to get the same result as your jsfiddle but using simple_form. I updated question with the simpleform code in my view.